# python requests with proxy ssl error in mac_os

Tags: python

im trying to use requests session to crawler some websit i use the proxy whith session but i get
this err and im try to use this code in windows sys it work.....
im also try to search in google and use this params verify=False but it also not work

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)')))

code is here

```
import requests
sess = requests.session()
sess.get('https://www.google.com',
              proxies={'https': 'https://100.25.43.154:3128'})
```